# Can't link 64-bit object file into an executable with MinGW32 gcc / ld

Tags: windows, assembly, gcc, mingw, ld

I just started learning assembly, but when i tried to compile the code i just get an error.

I can make the object file with `nasm -f win64 main.asm -o main.o` but when i try to use `ld -o main main.o` or `gcc -o main main.o` i just get an error saying `main.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized`. I tried to use wsl and there ld worked fine but I don't want to use that whenever I need to compile.

I am running windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: Where did you get the toolchain from?  What are the versions of `ld` and `gcc` and is that a 32 bit or a 64 bit toolchain?

Comment: @fuz ld is version 2.32 and gcc is version 9.2.0. I am using mingw32.

Comment: Ok.  Then try to get the 64 bit version.  It is possible that mingw32 does not understand 64 bit Windows object files.

Comment: @fuz How do I get that. [link](https://www.mingw.org/) is down.

Comment: Try [this site](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the toolchain I was using was 32-bit and only managed to link 32-bit object files while my object file was 64-bit. This caued my error and when I updated to a 64-bit toolchain it worked.